# App Engine: Can I upload my local dev_appserver.datastore to the live datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've been reading about the remote_api and the bulkloader.yaml configuration file for doing bulk uploads of Google App Engine, but all I really want to do is replace my live datastore on the cloud with the contents of my local datastore.  From what I've read, it would seem that I have to first somehow convert my dev_appserver.datastore file into csv or xml, and then apply all the fancy transforms of bulkloader.yaml, which seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Anyone know if there's an easier way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might work to run `download_data` against localhost and then `upload_data`, using that dump, against your live app... does it?

Comment: This is correct - you can dump the dev_appserver, then restore to production.

Comment: When I try this I just get a 405 Error, with no description or information. Here's what it looked like: (Sorry for the formatting, I can't figure out how to make it better) `>appcfg.py download_data --file=local.db --url=http://localhost:8080 --application=<MYAPPID> Please enter login credentials for localhost Email: <MY-EMAIL> Password for <MY-EMAIL>: [INFO ] Connecting to localhost:8080 Error 405: --- begin server output --- --- end server output ---

Comment: @jiffer `--url` should be `http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api` (you need `remote_api: on` in your `app.yaml` under `builtins`), and since downloading entities of all kinds at once isn't supported on the development server, you'll need to download them `--kind` by `--kind`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm away from my development computer for the weekend, but I'll try this on Monday.  I pretty sure this approach is just what I was looking for, so I'll mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Going to use this approach to life an existing blog onto app engine. Thanks!