# Will app engine python automatically upload local datastore to serve after deploying?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Using python app engine, I have some data on local datastore. Will the local datastore be uploaded to app engine server after deploy? If not, how can I upload them to the server in the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be automatically uploaded.

See the [Uploading and Downloading Data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) page on the AppEngine docs for details on how to best upload bulk data to your app.

Comment: there is also a somewhat related question with answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937725/app-engine-can-i-upload-my-local-dev-appserver-datastore-to-the-live-datastore

Comment: i think maybe manage.py dumpdata >data.json, manage.py remoate loaddata data.json will work. testing it.