# send data from localhost to app engine entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost, google-cloud-datastore

I used to do this a while back (about 3 years ago). I don't remember how, so maybe someone here can help me.

I create some entities in localhost datastore. Now I need to transfer the entities to the production datastore. I have existing entities in the store that I do not wish to delete. I just want to admit the additional data to production. Any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937725/app-engine-can-i-upload-my-local-dev-appserver-datastore-to-the-live-datastore may help, though more modern approaches (not focused on local-to-live uploads but usable for that too) are detailed at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin (still beta, though, I believe).

Comment: When I used to do it the process involved using the terminal.The SO link you provide seems to have some hint; but I haven't done this in so long that the scant info there is not enough help. As for the google link, it's not clear to me that I understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) for your application, then use a locally running program to auth to the remote API and do datastore operations. This is outlined on the docs paged linked.